# How to convert date of format dd MMM, yyyy into dd/MM/yyyy in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to convert date into above mentioned format. I have used:
 DateTime date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
But it gives exception as string is not recognized as a valid date time.

Note:date is of a string datatype and it is in dd MMM, yyyy format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# ASP.Net Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458054/c-sharp-asp-net-date-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> string is not recognized as a valid date time

Because you're trying to parse the date string from this format:

```
"dd/MM/yyyy"
```

But, as you state, the date string is in *this* format:

```
"dd MMM, yyyy"
```

`ParseExact` means just that... *exact*.  Parse the date from the format it's in:

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd MMM, yyyy", null);
```

Then you can output that value in any format you like:

```
date1.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

`ParseExact` takes the source format as second parameter. Try to use `DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd MMM, yyyy", null);`.

Answer (score 0):

@David beat me to the answer, but I just want to add that you should use `TryParseExact` rather than `ParseExact`. That way, you can recover from potential problems. For example:

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "dd MMM, yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime date2))
{
    date2.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
else
{
    // handle date in incorrect format
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can yo please try this:

```
        string dateString = "15 Jun, 2017";
        DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd MMM, yyyy", null);

        // Changing to dd/MM/yyyy
        string myDate = result.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```